# How to let each page's code in Fragment when using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I use the `ViewPager`, its adapter need to load `View`, these `View` just be built through `LayoutInflater.inflater`.

But I don't know each page' code write to where, I don't want to let all page's code in `MainActivity`(That controls ViewPager), I want to let each page's code in different file or class.

could u tell me how to do this.:D

Comment: [`FragmentPagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) is the magic word. :)

Comment: @MH.I got it~Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

**I want to let each page's code in different file or class.**

Create a Java class with a method say inflateViews and pass your context of activity to that method

```
void inflateViews(Context context) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_inflated, null);


    }
```

More details on **LayoutInflater** are [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)